Can't include static files in the build directory with Vercel
I'm writing a server app in Go and deploying it on Vercel.
The compiled binary is being placed somewhere else by Vercel, and the directory it is located in does not include the static files the binary needs to function!
I remember once in the past I used includeFiles to transfer static files along side the binary but I can't remember how I did it.
This is my vercel.json file:
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "cmd/serverless/main.go",
      "use": "@vercel/go",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": [
          "public/**/*" // Here are the files the binary needs.
        ]
      }
    }
  ],

  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "cmd/serverless/main.go"
    }
  ]
}


Somehow the binary still can't find the files so I am assuming they haven't been transferred.

What version of vercel CLI are you working with?
